# Serializing/Saving the values of a custom class?

Tags: visualforce, reporting, class, wrapper-class

Would it be possible to create a custom class whose values can be saved, and then possibly even reported on, without creating a custom object behind it?

The reason I ask for this is because this custom classes fields will be modified on a per use basis, and I need to save and report on all the data that is entered.

I'm already familiar with the Metadata API so I can create the fields or save new custom objects, and I know how to save a custom objects records, but recording something without an object seems to be a rather illusive piece of information.

Comment: Conversion between graphs of Apex objects and JSON strings works quite well so you can store complex graphs in JSON format in "Text Area (Long)" SObject fields and pull them back into Apex objects when you need to. But it will only be your code that can handle these fields (so e.g. no reports). Sometimes it makes sense to go this way nevertheless.